# .NET open-source editor for small images

Tags: .net, image-processing, open-source, editor, bitmap

Is there any open-source .NET graphic editor for small images (where each pixel can be edited separately). I want to integrate it in my software. It may looks like this:
[image]

EDIT: In fact, I only need support for black&white images.

Comment: You don't need .NET for this. The [source code](http://www.computerhistory.org/highlights/macpaint/) for MacPaint has been released, all written in a combination of 68000 assembly and Pascal.

Comment: You want to integrate a component that is capable to do the same thing as what the program shows?

Comment: If you want to do this editing inside your application then make it clear in your question. Otherwise there's a good chance it will get migrated to Super User or closed as off topic.

Comment: The Paint that comes with all versions of Windows can do this.

Comment: But I cannot integrate in to my software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do this in [Paint .Net](http://www.getpaint.net/).  It's not limited to small images, but you can definitely manipulate small images.

**EDIT**

Sorry, it looks like the source code is [no longer officially available](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/15839-request-for-comments-paintnet-v35-source-code-release/).

Comment: I think he wants to do the editing in his .Net project, but not 100% sure

Comment: Yes. I want it to be a part of my software. How can I get sources of Paint.Net?